# Extend functionality of commands such as reboot to record a reason

Tags: linux, logs, reboot

Is it possible to extend the functionality of system commands such as `reboot`, `shutdown -r now` or `init 6` so that when they are issued, the user must enter a reason and other information as part of an audit trail? Like Windows servers.

So after entered the purpose of reboot, it has to store somewhere in the log like for example purpose should contain change number, date, which user has executed the command.

Comment: If `sudo` was used, then `auth.log` will contain the timestamp, user and command details.

Comment: This is a Q&A site where question non-relevant chit-chat, like your experience level with Linux,  is unwelcome in a posts (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)). Your question is also unclear, because I one of the lucky ones that seldom use windows servers. Are you asking for a command to prompt you to specify a reason for any of those actions (which it then logs), before executing them?

Comment: Unix and Linux let you make a script to replace *any* command ... you can then run the original command in the script via a full path reference

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are not familiar with Windows Servers, I will take a moment to explain the comparison. When a Windows Server is asked to shutdown or restart, the GUI prompts the user to provide a reason for the request, that is then recorded in an audit log. (This is optional for a PowerShell (command line) reboot request.) Moreover, when a Windows Server starts without having had a reason for the restart it prompts suitably privileged users for a reason for the restart the next time they log in to the system.

---

Your suggestion is possible - up to a point. You would have to consider what should happen if a `reboot` command is issued from a scheduled task or other place where no administrative user is logged on. You would also need to consider how far you would want to go with your scenario - were you looking to provide a simple audit trail or one baked in so deeply into the system that it was close to impossible to bypass. Obviously there would be an increased cost with the latter.

One way of handling this is to move a command such as `reboot` to, say, `reboot.bin`. Then create a script called `reboot` that prompted either via the GUI or the command line for the necessary reason and other information. This would be written via the `syslog` to an appropriate log file (perhaps `auth.log`). The process could be repeated for your other "protected" commands. Note that there would be nothing other than etiquette stopping your privileged users running the real `reboot.bin` (etc.) directly.

**The [`molly-guard` package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/molly-guard.8.html) implements this**, by running a series of scripts before executing the real command.

Another way of handling this would be to take the source code for the "protected" commands and extend them natively. Harder work, and only slightly harder to circumvent. (Mind you, it's not difficult to bypass the shutdown dialog on Windows either - just use the command line.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion roaima. I will try it but it's okay for reboot but there's another way to reboot the server using these commands telinit 6, init 6, shutdown -r now. How could we do that.

Comment: @Ashoka same process but different commands.

Comment: @Ashoka answer updated to reference molly-guard, which sounds like it's almost exactly what you need